# Kafka brokers shuts down because log dirs have failed

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I have a 3 broker Kafka clusters with the Kafka logs in the /tmp directory. I am running Debezium Source Connector to MongoDB which polls data from 4 collections.

However within 5 mins after starting the connector, the Kafka brokers are shutting down with the following error:

```
[2020-04-16 18:25:08,642] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in /tmp/kafka-logs-1 have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

I have tried the different suggestions viz. Deleting the Kafka logs and cleaning out the Zookeeper logs. But I ran into the same problem again.

I have also noticed that the kafka logs occupy 100% of the /tmp directory when this happens. So I have also changed the log retention policy based on size.

```
log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=10000
```

This also turned up to be futile. 
I would like to have some assistance regarding this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using /tmp as log dir for Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log files got corrupted probably because you've ran out of storage.

---

I would suggest to change `log.dirs` in `server.properties`. Also make sure that you don't use the `tmp/` location, as this is going to be purged once your machine turns off. Once you have changed `log.dirs` you can restart Kafka.

Note that the older messages will be lost.

Comment: Thanks! I moved my logs to a more permanent location with larger disk space. The Kafka cluster is running fine now.